How to send variables to called-workflow from the caller-workflow
I am migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions.
In Jenkins, I made use of
build job: 'Configurations/configure_values', parameters: [
    string(name: 'param1', value: value1), 
    string(name: 'param2', value: value2),
    string(name: 'param3', value: value3)
    ]

to call/trigger another pipeline.
In GitHub Action, I have:

Called.yml is a configuration pipeline.
Caller.yml is used to clone
a set a configurations and send multiple requests to called.yml to
do those configurations.

What it does?
caller.yml reads values from test.csv
Caller.yml calls called.yml multiple times.
Example: My test.csv file has
a,x,1
b,y,2
c,z,3

called.yml expects three inputs. Now, the caller.yml should call called.yml three times.

Iteration: a,x,1
Iteration: b,y,2
Iteration: c,z,3

Problem:
Caller.yml successfully called.yml, but the input parameters are going as empty to the called.yml.
Please see values of value and name
createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ***" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/config' --data '{"distributed": true,"expirySettings": {"": {"value": ""},"valuesNull": false},"name": "","overflowToDisk": false,"skipCacheIfElementSizeInKBExceeds": xxx}'

Caller.yml:
name: Caller

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [abc]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: List files (Start)
        run: |
            ls

      - name: Read CSV and trigger workflows
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          ls
          ....
      - name: List files (End)
        run: |
          ls
          cd .github/workflows
  call-ASGW-Config-Cache:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/called.yml
    secrets: inherit
    permissions:
      contents: read

    with: 
        cacheName: "auto"
        expirationType: "timeoutInSec"
        expirationTime: "200"

called.yml:
name: called
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      cacheName:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Cache Name'
      expirationType:
        type: choice
        options:
          - timeoutInSec
          - timeOfDay
          - date
      expirationTime:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Expiration Time in Secods'
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      cacheName:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Cache Name'
      expirationType:
        type: string
      expirationTime:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Expiration Time in Secods'
jobs:
  Create_Update-Cache:
    runs-on: [abc]
    steps:
      - name: Execute cURL
        run: |
            createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/config' --data '{"distributed": true,"Settings": {"${{ github.event.inputs.expirationType }}": {"value": "${{ github.event.inputs.expirationTime }}"},"valuesNull": false},"name": "${{ github.event.inputs.cacheName }}","overflowToDisk": false,"skipCacheIfElementSizeInKBExceeds": 123}'`
      echo "$createresponse"
 
      if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
      then
        echo "***Created successfully***"
        echo "createresponse = $createresponse"
      elif [[ $createresponse == *"409"* ]];
      then
        updateresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.APIGEEDEVFUNCTIONALUSER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --url 'https://example.com/config/${{ github.event.inputs.cacheName }}' --data '{"distributed": true,"Settings": {"${{ github.event.inputs.expirationType }}": {"value": "${{ github.event.inputs.expirationTime }}"},"valuesNull": false},"name": "${{ github.event.inputs.cacheName }}","overflowToDisk": false,"skipCacheIfElementSizeInKBExceeds": 123}'`
        echo "updateresponse = $updateresponse"
 
        if [[ $updateresponse == *"200"* ]];
        then
          echo "***Cache updated successfully***"
          echo "updateresponse = $updateresponse"
        else
          echo "Failed with $updateresponse"
        fi
      else
        echo "Failed with $createresponse"
      fi
      echo "*** Task Completed ***"


cache.json:
[{"cacheName":"abc","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"100"}, {"cacheName":"def","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"200"}, {"cacheName":"ghi","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"300"}]
Main.yml:
name: ASGW-Bulk-Config-Cache.yml

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [abc]
    outputs:
      iterations: ${{ steps.set-iterations.outputs.values }}
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Read JSON and trigger workflows
      id: set-iterations
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        echo Saving iteration list output as Array
        # Join the array elements into a single JSON array
        json_array=$(cat "cache.json")
        echo "List: $json_array"
        echo "values=$json_array" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Check list
      run: |
        echo ${{ steps.set-iterations.outputs.values }}

  call-ASGW-Config-Cache:
    needs: [build]
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        iteration: ${{fromJson(needs.build.outputs.iterations)}}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ASGW-Config-Cache.yml
    secrets: inherit
    permissions:
      contents: read
    with: 
      cacheName: ${{ matrix.iteration.cacheName }}
      expirationType: ${{ matrix.iteration.expirationType }}
      expirationTime: ${{ matrix.iteration.expirationTime }}

  check:
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: [abc]
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        iteration: ${{fromJson(needs.build.outputs.iterations)}}
    steps:
      - name: Do something
        run: |
          echo Iteration
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.cacheName }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.expirationType }}
          echo ${{ matrix.iteration.expirationType }}

Called.yml:
name: ASGW-Config-Cache
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      cacheName:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Cache Name'
      expirationType:
        type: choice
        options:
          - timeoutInSec
          - timeOfDay
          - date
      expirationTime:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Expiration Time in Secods'
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      cacheName:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Cache Name'
      expirationType:
        type: string
      expirationTime:
        type: string
        description: 'Provide Expiration Time in Secods'
jobs:
  Create_Update-Cache:
    runs-on: [abc]
    steps:
      - name: Execute cURL
        run: |
          createresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --url 'https://example.com/caches' --data '{"distributed": true,"expirySettings": {"${{ inputs.expirationType }}": {"value": "${{ inputs.expirationTime }}"},"valuesNull": false},"name": "${{ inputs.cacheName }}","overflowToDisk": false,"skipCacheIfElementSizeInKBExceeds": 1000}'`
          echo "$createresponse"
     
          if [[ $createresponse == *"201"* ]];
          then
            echo "***Cache created successfully***"
            echo "createresponse = $createresponse"
          elif [[ $createresponse == *"409"* ]];
          then
            updateresponse=`curl -k --write-out '%{http_code}' --header "authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.USER }}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --url 'https://example.com/caches/${{ inputs.cacheName }}' --data '{"distributed": true,"expirySettings": {"${{ inputs.expirationType }}": {"value": "${{ inputs.expirationTime }}"},"valuesNull": false},"name": "${{ inputs.cacheName }}","overflowToDisk": false,"skipCacheIfElementSizeInKBExceeds": 1000}'`
            echo "updateresponse = $updateresponse"
     
            if [[ $updateresponse == *"200"* ]];
            then
              echo "***Cache updated successfully***"
              echo "updateresponse = $updateresponse"
            else
              echo "Failed with $updateresponse"
            fi
          else
            echo "Failed with $createresponse"
          fi
          echo "*** Task Completed ***"


How is your name: Execute cURL step configured in the called.yml file?

Called.yml can be triggered solely to configure single entries. - This workflow works.
Please find the work flow code in the question.

Added an answer with the details :)

You're not using the correct syntax to manipulate your inputs in the called.yaml file.

Inputs example for workflow_call
Inputs example for workflow_dispatch

The available inputs in your workflow are:

${{ inputs.cacheName }}
${{ inputs.expirationType }}
${{ inputs.expirationTime }}.

In that case, you should replace:

${{ github.event.inputs.Type }} by ${{ inputs.expirationType }}
${{ github.event.inputs.Time }} by ${{ inputs.expirationTime }}
${{ github.event.inputs.name }} by ${{ inputs.cacheName }}

Idem in the other curl commands where you used those inputs.

Regarding the multiple iterations, my suggestion would be to use a matrix strategy using an object for each iteration.
I've built an example below:

main workflow
reusable workflow
Successful run


This works! we are still missing one more step :  Caller.yml calls called.yml multiple times. Please see my Iteration explanation in the question.

I've added an example to the answer for the multiple iteration process

sorry for the delay in response! I have updated the question with cache.json, Main.yml, and 'called.yml` .
The code isn't working on my machine :D
ASGW-Bulk-Config-Cache.yml: .github#L1 Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'call-ASGW-Config-Cache'. .github/workflows/ASGW-Bulk-Config-Cache.yml (Line: 32, Col: 20): Unexpected type of value '[{"cacheName":"abc","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"100"}, {"cacheName":"def","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"200"}, {"cacheName":"ghi","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"300"}]', expected type: Sequence.

Could you edit the question adding this matrix strategy configuration there? It's more difficult to check through comments on StackOverflow :)

Please note, I'm using v3 steps:     - name: Checkout repository       uses: actions/checkout@v3 .
V4 throws: Unable to resolve action actions/checkout@v4, unable to find version v4

This actions/checkout does have a v4 tag as you can check here. Did you maybe misspell v4 for V4?

Agreed :) Main.yml has the matrix strategy under call-ASGW-Config-Cache

Could you share what is printed on the runner in your echo "List: $json_array" step please? (after the json_array=$(cat "cache.json"))

Here you go :)
List: '[{"cacheName":"abc","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"100"}, {"cacheName":"def","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"200"}, {"cacheName":"ghi","expirationType":"int","expirationTime":"300"}]'

Looks like those additional quotes were the problem.

It's working now. Thanks a lot, GuiFalourd!! :)

Perfect! I'm glad the example helped :D
